# VBA Excel - Proper Case Exceptions?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro written to convert customer names and titles to proper case if they aren't already. The problem with that is I sometimes have a list with abbreviations or acronyms (ie "High School" = "HS" ; Limited Partnership = "LP").

The issue is that my macro will proper case what should remain in upper case. To work around this I have a few exceptions written into my macro. Here's an example:

```
Dim fndList As Variant
Dim rplcList As Variant
Dim F As Long

fndList = Array("'S", "Xdock", "Llc", "Us ", "Urs", "Lc ", "Bbq", "Dq")
rplcList = Array("'s", "XDock", "LLC", "US ", "URS", "LC ", "BBQ", "DQ")

For F = 0 To UBound(fndList)
Selection.Replace What:=fndList(F), Replacement:=rplcList(F), _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
    SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Is there a way to write a rule that recognizes if the term is not a word then it defaults to upper case?

The other issue I have with my temporary solution is that some words containing the array will revert to upper case (ie: "Famous" = "FamoUS" ; "Alcohol" = "ALCohol" ; "Yourselves" = `YoURSelves").

Appreciate any help, pleae let me know if you require more info on my part.

Comment: No, there is not.  Excel does not "see" words.  It cannot tell the difference between `us` as in you and me, and `US` as in the United States.

Comment: imo: This is a losing battle.

Comment: Look into _regular expressions_; in VBA you can reference and use the VBScript regex engine, which has a few limitations but should suffice for this, assuming you're trying to tell `Famous` from `US`, not `US` from `us`.